# How to display mat-select with a default value on load

Tags: html, angular, typescript, drop-down-menu

Here is my markup:

```
  <mat-form-field class="col-md-3" *ngIf="isShown">
    <mat-select placeholder="Status" formControlName="batchStatus" [value]="selected">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let Status of statusList"[value]="status.referenceDetailCode">
        {{ status.referenceDetailValue }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

ts code :

```
this.isShown = true;
this.selected = res.status;
```

With the above code, dropdown is not getting selected with the status that I'm setting in my typescript file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked by doing this :
       `this.displayForm.controls.status.setValue(this.selected);`